# Can I run Snappy Ubuntu Core as a guest inside Docker?

Tags: virtualization, docker, ubuntu-core

I'm aware that Snappy Ubuntu can host Docker containers. My question is whether it can also be run inside a container, as a Docker guest.

The reason I'm asking is that I can't find any Snappy VM guest containers in the public Docker repository.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can: Snappy is just a stripped down version of Ubuntu, and Ubuntu works inside Docker. The fact that Snappy does not appear inside the public Docker repository implies that you have to do things manually.

1. First, get the latest image:

   ```
   wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/preview/ubuntu-core-alpha-02_amd64-virt.img
   ```

   This file is a QCOW2 image meant for QEMU/KVM, but we can extract its contents for Docker too.
2. In order to access the files inside a QCOW2 image, you'll need `qemu-nbd`, so install it and run:

   ```
   qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 ubuntu-core-alpha-02_amd64-virt.img
   ```

   This command will create a "virtual disk" named `/dev/ndb0`, with "virtual partitions" named `/dev/ndb0pX`. Use `fdisk -l /dev/nbd0` to get an idea of what partitions are inside the QCOW2 image.
3. The partition you are interested in is `/dev/ndb0p3`, so mount it:

   ```
   mount /dev/ndb0p3 /somewhere
   ```
4. You are almost done! Just follow [Docker's guide on custom base images](https://docs.docker.com/articles/baseimages/):

   ```
   tar -C /somewhere -c . | docker import - snappy
   ```

Now you are ready to create your Snappy images on top of that base image. For example, I created a *snappy_test* image with the *xkcd-webserver* app installed. Here's the `Dockerfile` I used:

```
FROM snappy:latest
RUN snappy install xkcd-webserver
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Isn't there a public Docker image for Snappy?

Comment: Can you please revisit your answer? It seems like that your solution does not work anymore with the current ubuntu-core  image: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/stable/current/ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz

Comment: @Karl2011 I'll try to look into it as soon as I have some free time :)