# Snappy Ubuntu Core: snap installation doesn't copy files

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-core

I created a Docker base image running Snappy Ubuntu Core 15.04 amd64 using the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/577248/495667 (you can get my image from Dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/r/mrjogo/snappy/). However, when I try to install a snap within the container, it does not copy over the files correctly (note I'm running as root):

```
# rsyslogd

# snappy install hello-world
Installing hello-world
Starting download of hello-world
21.60 KB / 21.60 KB [====================================] 100.00 % 135.39 KB/s 
Done
Starting download of icon for package
33.77 KB / 33.77 KB [====================================] 100.00 % 209.61 KB/s 
Done
Name          Date       Version Developer 
ubuntu-core   2016-01-15 12      ubuntu    
hello-world   2016-01-20 1.0.18  canonical 
webdm         2016-01-15 0.11    canonical 
generic-amd64 2016-01-15 1.4     canonical 

# showdev
bash: showdev: command not found

# /apps/hello-world.canonical/1.0.18/bin/showdev 
Hello /dev World: Here is what I can see with 'find /dev/'
/dev/
/dev/log
/dev/kcore
/dev/stderr
/dev/stdout
/dev/stdin
/dev/fd
/dev/console
/dev/ptmx
/dev/random
/dev/urandom
/dev/tty
/dev/full
/dev/zero
/dev/null
/dev/fuse
/dev/mqueue
/dev/shm
/dev/pts
/dev/pts/ptmx

Here is hardware that has been assigned to me ():

# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# ls /bin | grep showdev

#
```

(side note: not sure why, but I have to start rsyslogd manually or I get logger errors)

Since I'm new to snappy I'm not sure if it's a function of how the container was created, how it's run, misunderstanding how snaps are installed, or a bug. I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the command as

```
# hello-world.showdev
```