# How to test snapcraft package inside container with realistic confinement?

Tags: ubuntu-core

We want to run integrationtests for our software packaged as snap in an environment with the same confinements as it is running later on the hardware device installed with ubuntu-core. We want to ensure we don't run into any problems caused by the confinement (e.g. missing binaries or snap interfaces).

What would be the best way to do this? I had the following ideas, but none really convinced me:

- Build an Ubuntu Core docker-container and start the application inside the container: this would be the preferred way, but I didn't find any possibility to build a working ubuntu-core 16 container (there are howtos to repack the qemu-img, but there are no binaries in the partition). Also I don't know how to invoke a binary inside a snap so it is running inside the snap confinement just like it would if started as daemon by the snapd.
- Use the "normal" ubuntu docker baseimage, install snapd and install our snap: I fear this will result in a not restricted enough OS and we won't run into the same problems like we would on a real Ubuntu-Core.

Comment: This is a good question. I also searching for a solution. The closest solution I found is this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/566736/can-i-run-snappy-ubuntu-core-as-a-guest-inside-docker
but proposed solution isn't working anymore.